# Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@si was complete

Tags: titlesec

I've searched for similar errors, and usually it has to do with using `\titleformat` instead of `\titleformat*`

This is what I am using

```
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\color{gray}}
```

However, it gives me the error:

```
Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@si was complete.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. If I comment out the above line, then everything works, but, of course, the style isn't how I'd like.

The full file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{chapterStyle}
\usepackage{appendices}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\hyphenpenalty=100000
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,headsep=0.2in,footskip=0.1in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\phantomsec}[1]{\phantomsection\label{#1}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead{} % remove everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand\sectionbreak{\ifnum\value{chapter}>1\ifnum\value{section}>1\clearpage\fi\fi}
\newcommand\subsectionbreak{\ifnum\value{chapter}=6\ifnum\value{subsection}>1\clearpage\fi\fi}

\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large \color{gray}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{2}
\pagebreak
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\listofappendices
\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{sloppypar}
    \include{./introduction}
    \include{./running}
    \include{./creatingproject}
    \include{./managing}
    \include{./configurationfiles}
    \include{./workflow}
    \include{./end}
    \include{./appendex}
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

The chapterStyle package looks like the below, and appears to be causing the issue:

```
\ProvidesPackage{chapterStyle}[2017/09/23]
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{4cm}
\newcommand{\chaptertitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
        \fontsize{120}{110}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
        \raggedleft%
        \hfill{\chaptertitlefont#1}\\
        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
        \mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
        \raggedleft%
        \hfill{\chaptertitlefont#1}\\
        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}

\endinput
```

Comment: Your code doesn't provide any error for me, can you provide the full `MWE`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi, I've edited to include what the main .tex file has.

Comment: @ChrisMM To test the code, I removed some things that I don't have, i.e., `\usepackage{chapterStyle}` and `\usepackage{appendices}`, and all the `\include` statements with the chapters, and then I added a chapter, section, subsection and subsubsection, and then the code worked without problems (producing a large gray subsubsection title). So the issue must be somewhere in the files that I removed from the code. I would particularly suspect this `chapterStyle` package (because of the name). Can you tell us what the content of that package is?

Comment: @ChrisMM What `Marijin` said is correct, can you check the content for `chapterStyle.sty` and `appendices`, hope these two packages caused the error....

Comment: @Marijn, I've included the `chapterStyle` file. Removing it does fix the issue, although I'm unsure as to why it causes a conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the option `explicit` in `titlesec` package, then you have to code the `unnumbered head` as like bleow:

```
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large \color{gray}}{}{}{#1}
```

Above changes will helps you to meet the requirement...